# Datadog Lambda Extension Logs delayed

Tags: aws-lambda, datadog

Im trying to send logs from AWS Lambda using Datadog extension.

It works but the logs arent being sent until the lambda is shut down (as opposed to the end of invocation) which leads to ~10min delay before logs appear within Datadog.

The current environment variables for the lambda are as follows:

```
DD_API_KEY_SECRET_ARN = secert_arn
DD_CAPTURE_LAMBDA_PAYLOAD = true
DD_ENV = dev
DD_FLUSH_TO_LOG = false
DD_LAMBDA_HANDLER = index.handler
DD_LOG_LEVEL = debug
DD_LOGS_INJECTION = true
DD_SERVERLESS_LOGS_ENABLED = true
DD_SERVICE = MyService
DD_SITE = datadoghq.com
DD_TRACE_ENABLED = true
DD_VERSION  $LATEST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at this issue:
https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-lambda-extension/issues/29

Let me quote an answer from it:

> Hi @stalar, thanks for reaching out.
>
> This is a known behavior based on the way Lambda Extensions and the
> Lambda Logs API work. Once your function finishes running, the
> extension is frozen until the next invocation. However, there isn't a
> guarantee that we have received logs at that time. Logs may arrive on
> the subsequent invocation of the function. Furthermore, if your
> function is invoked repeatedly, we will switch to a strategy of
> periodically flushing logs to reduce overhead, which may mean that
> logs do not immediately appear in Datadog after each and every
> invocation.
>
> We are in touch with AWS about possible improvements to resolve this
> issue.
>
> Let me know if you have any further questions!